# ignoring img tags while searching for urls in string

Tags: php, regex

I have the following code in which I am replacing urls with hyperlinked anchor tags,

```
public function urlify($string)
{

    //FIND URLS INSIDE TEXT
    //The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(((http(s?)(:\/\/))?([w]{3}\.)?)([a-z0-9]+\.)*([a-z|0-9])+\.(com(\.au)?|org|me|net|ly|be|gl|info|(co(\.))?uk|ca|nz|tv)((\/[^\s]+)*)+)/i";

    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $string, $url)) {

        if (strpos($url[0], ":") === false) {
            $link = 'http://' . $url[0];
        } else {
            $link = $url[0];
        }

        // make the urls hyper links
        $string = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $url[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $url[0] . '</a>', $string);
    }

    return $string;
}
```

But I want to ignore all img tags while searching for urls, I have no idea how can I go for it.

Comment: Just need to check if URL contains image file extension in it. However it's also possible that URL doesn't contain origin file name (i.e. cause is generated hash for security reasons) in such case only way is to fetch resource and check its MIME

Comment: @biesior can't we modify regular expression to ignore all img tags ?

Comment: You should try using something like DOMDocument instead as regex'es can easily cause problems.  DOMDocument allows you to understand the context of the content as well as the type of nodes you are working with.

Comment: @ShoyebSheikh the way how yo will check the string is up to you, regular expression is one of them. The problem is with URLs generated for i.e. for security reasons, like `http://domain.tld/resource.php?id=12345abc`. in such case string comparison will has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @Biesor and @Nigel Ren I came up with this,

```
public function urlify($string)
{

    //FIND URLS INSIDE TEXT
    //The Regular Expression filter
    $reg_exUrl = "/(((http(s?)(:\/\/))?([w]{3}\.)?)([a-z0-9]+\.)*([a-z|0-9])+\.(com(\.au)?|org|me|net|ly|be|gl|info|(co(\.))?uk|ca|nz|tv)((\/[^\s]+)*)+)/i";

    $htmlDom = new DOMDocument;
    $htmlDom->loadHTML($string);
    $imageTags = $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('img');
    $img_srcs = array();
    foreach($imageTags as $imageTag){
        $img_srcs[] = $imageTag->getAttribute('src');
        $imageTag->setAttribute('src', ''); 
    }        
    $string = $htmlDom->saveHTML();

    // Check if there is a url in the text
    if (preg_match($reg_exUrl, $string, $url)) {

        if (strpos($url[0], ":") === false) {
            $link = 'http://' . $url[0];
        } else {
            $link = $url[0];
        }

        // make the urls hyper links
        $string = preg_replace($reg_exUrl, '<a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $url[0] . '" target="_blank">' . $url[0] . '</a>', $string);
    }

    foreach($imageTags as $key => $imageTag){
        $imageTag->setAttribute('src', $img_srcs[$key]); 
    }
    $string = $htmlDom->saveHTML();
    $p =  $htmlDom->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0);
    if($p)
    { 
        $string = implode(
            "",
            array_map([$htmlDom, 'saveHTML'], iterator_to_array($p->childNodes))
        );
    }

    return $string;
}
```

For the time being I am using this till some better solution comes up.